# How do I change the x and y axis on the results histogram for a ibmq_qasm.simulation resulting histogram?

Tags: simulation, ibm-quantum-devices

Im following a textbook and when they ran the same circuit with the ibmq_qasm_simulator, their results histogram had computational basis state on the x axis and probability on the y axis, however my results from the simulator gave me a histogram with measurement outcome in hexadecimal on the x axis and frequency on the y axis. Is there a way to change the ibmq_qasm_simulator result’s histogram to a computational basis states and probability histogram rather than the measurement outcome in hexadecimal and frequency histogram I am getting?

Thanks im new to ibm quantum, any help would be appreciated